# JSON web token error when authorising a Github Action

Tags: connected-apps, github-actions, openssl

I'm trying to create a Github action to authorise a Github action and then create a scratch org to run tests against, but I keep getting the below error when trying to authorise. How can I debug this?

I created the certificate following [the steps here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth_key_and_cert.htm) using openssl

```
- name: Authenticate Against Dev Hub
  run: sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid ${{ secrets.SF_APP_KEY_PROD }} --jwtkeyfile keys/server.key --username ${{ secrets.SF_USERNAME_PROD }} --instanceurl ${{ secrets.SF_INSTANCE_URL_PROD }} --setdefaultdevhubusername -a DevHub
```

> ERROR running auth:jwt:grant:  We encountered a JSON web token error,
> which is likely not an issue with Salesforce CLI. Here’s the error:
> error:1E08010C:DECODER routines::unsupported

Comment: Did you happen to set a password on the `server.key`

Comment: Challenge Password? Yes I've tried with and without setting this when creating the cert. No difference

Comment: And you have uploaded the public cert successfully to your Connected App?

Comment: Yep. Figured it out, was missing -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- & -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----- in my server.key

Comment: Be sure to add this as an answer to benefit the Community

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, was missing `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` & `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` in my server.key as I'd copied it into an environment variable.